# Удаление от начало строки до символа включительно

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такая строка: `about/русские буквы с пробелами и цифрами`
Как составить паттерн что бы удалить из этой строки все до знака / включительно?
Использую такой код:

```
$pat = '';
$str = 'about/русские буквы с пробелами и цифрами';
preg_match($pat, $str, $matches)
```

Comment: `preg_replace('/^[^\/]+/', '', $string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'about/русские буквы с пробелами и цифрами';
echo preg_replace('/^[^\/]+/', '', $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/DF6C3

Если нужно удалить вместе со слэшем, то:

```
$str = 'about/русские буквы с пробелами и цифрами';
echo preg_replace('/^[^\/]+\//', '', $str)
```

https://3v4l.org/dCWkG

Comment: Если требуется удалить вместе со слэшем, просто добавьте его в маску `/^[^\/]+\//`

Comment: удалить надо с начала до слеша включительно)

Comment: @helldrg, так зачем вы используйте `preg_match`, используйте `preg_replace`.

Comment: я планирую доработать его потом, что бы строка делилась на ключ и значение

Comment: @helldrg, функция preg_match не предполагает удаление из строки чего-либо. Она лишь делает поиск в ней.

Comment: спасибо большое, буду знать. Подскажите как найти тогда все от слеша до конца

Comment: @helldrg, `/\/\K[^$]+/`

Comment: Спасибо!!! А не подскажете еще, что сделать, что бы символы выводились русские корректно)

Comment: @helldrg, https://3v4l.org/XBc8p

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @helldrg отметьте ответ, если он вам помог.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo ltrim(strstr('about/русские буквы с пробелами и цифрами', '/'), '/');

// для ключ - значение:    
print_r(explode('/', 'about/русские буквы с пробелами и цифрами'));
// в ключе [0] - ключ, в ключе [1] - значение
```

Comment: `в ключе [0] - ключ` как так получилось то? ) Там ведь тоже значение...

Comment: ТС говорит "я планирую доработать его потом, что бы строка делилась на ключ и значение". Вот после експлода есть и ключ и значение. Хотя я может неправильно толкую эту фразу и ключом должно быть что-то другое.

Comment: Вот, надо было его цитату и вставить. А то "в ключе ключ" звучит интересно

Comment: Спасибо большое! Если не получится preg_match использовать, то этот код использую)

Comment: Использовать `preg_match` чтобы найти `/` в тексте - избыточно.

Comment: в данном контексте согласен. Просто у меня роутер работает используя preg_match с патернами типа  #^search/{text:\w+}$#. Не работают в этом примере русские символы, вот теперь придумываю костыли)